# ERROR : Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, build

So im trying to download a file using a given URL using the flutter_downloader package
Below is my implementation,

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
    debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to console
   );
   runApp(new MaterialApp(
   home: new MyApp(),
   ));
 }

 class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
  }

  class _State extends State<MyApp> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: Text('Template Code'),backgroundColor: 
         Colors.green,),
        body: Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: Center(child:Column(
          children: <Widget> [
           Text('Hello World'),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: () async {
              final status = await Permission.storage.request();

               if (status.isGranted) {
              final externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

              final id = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                url:
                "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4",
                savedDir: externalDir!.path,
                fileName: "download",
                showNotification: true,
                openFileFromNotification: true,
              );


            } else {
              print("Permission denied");
            }
        }),
      ],
    )),
  ),
);
}
}
```

when I run this on my emulator,I get this exception

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
> Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
> > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/HP/Desktop/OWASLO/care_giver_app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 31; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "provider" is not bound.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Please help!!!

Answer (score 10):

there is issue with manifest file

this line missing :   `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

in `manifest` tag

It should be like below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="app package name">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check-out this issue thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63114

Basically, steps you can try are:

1. Delete Gradle cache at `%USER_HOME%\.gradle/caches/` (It'll re-download the Gradle again)
2. Run `flutter clean`
3. Run `flutter pub get`